Asymptotics of system of quadratic ODEs on simplex
Consider the system ODEs
$$
x_k' = f(x) g_k(x)\,, \quad k=1,\ldots, n
$$
on a subset of the unit simplex $\Delta = \{x \in [0,1]^n : \sum_i x_i \leq 1\}$, namely
$$
S = \{x \in \Delta : f(x) \geq 0 \}\,.
$$
Here $ f$ and $ g_k$ are linear/affine functions, so the system makes sense. Moreover, let's assume that $g_k(x)=0$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ has a unique solution $ \bar x \in S$.
I am wondering what conditions on $f$ and $g_k$ may be sufficient or necessary to guarantee that a solution satisfies
$$
x(t) \to \bar x \quad as \quad t \to \infty \ \,,
$$
provided $f(x(0)) >0$?
In other words, I want to show that possible equilibria with $f(x)=0$ are not reached in infinite time.
In fact, I have particular system in mind,
for example, take $n=3$
with
$$
f(x) := 
3x_1+2 x_2 + x_3-1\,,
$$
and
$$
g_1(x) = x_2-x_1\\
g_2(x) = x_{3}+x_{1} - 2x_2\\
g_3(x)= 1- x_1-3x_3\ \ 
 ("= x_4 + x_2-2x_3") \,.
$$
In this case $g_k( \bar x)=0$ holds for the constant vector $ \bar x = (1/4,1/4,1/4)$. Viewing $ f(x) $ as a "state-dependent speed", the system should always run into $ \bar x $, when started with an initial condition such that $ f>0$.
Numerical simulations confirm this.
I tried (unsuccessfully) asymptotic analysis of the equilibria by studying the Jacobian of the system, which became quickly messy for general functions/large $n$.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
